# How to create a lookup table in Groovy?

Tags: groovy

I want to create a lookup table in Groovy, given a size (in this case the `size` is of `4`):

```
    RGGG
    RRGG
    RRRG
    RRRR
```

That is in first iteration only one `R` should be there and `size-1` times of `G` should be there. As per the iteration value increases `R` should grow and `G` should decrease as well. So for size `4` I will have `4` lookup values.

How one could do this in Groovy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mean like this:

```
def lut( width, a='R', b='G' ) {
  (1..width).collect { n ->
    ( a * n ) + ( b * ( width - n ) )
  }
}

def table = lut( 4 )

table.each { println it }
```

prints:

```
RGGG
RRGG
RRRG
RRRR
```

Your question doesn't really say what sort of data you are expecting out?  This code gives a `List` of `Strings`